# How to test If a post has a particular term

Tags: shortcode, description

I want to display a different description for a post if it belongs to a specific product category in a filter.

I've used the code below code to add the code but it is displaying for all products:

```php
function herara_filter_short_description( $desc ){
    global $product;
    if ( is_single( $product->id ) ) {
        $desc = '<span class="sku_wrapper">SKU: <span class="sku">'. $product->get_sku() .'</span></span></BR><span class="material_wrapper">MATERIAL: <span class="material">'. $product->get_sku() .'</span></span>';
    }
    return $desc;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'herara_filter_short_description' );
```

Comment: so you're asking if a post ( of type `product` ) has a particular term in a taxonomy? ( where the taxonomy is the woocommerce product category taxonomy? ). How to test if a post has a term in a taxonomy is a much better question that achieves the same thing and is 100x easier to find an answer for.

Comment: I've cleaned up your code and fixed an unrelated bug ( is `is_single` was false then `null` would be returned, overwriting any other filters, so I changed `$new_desc` to `$desc`. It's also not necessary to declare the `$product` global and pass its ID, the current post is already set to that product so it already knows which post to check

Comment: no not that, am talking about a product (Woocommerce), if the product is in the category XX a specific code should display in the short description.

Comment: Yes, products are posts of type `product`, much like pages are posts of type `page`, products are just another custom post type. Much like categories and tags are taxonomies, so are product categories, under the hood they're all the same. ( note that if they were not, then this Q would be off topic, 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here so your question would have been closed )

Comment: even the WooCommerce official docs say so https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/installed-taxonomies-post-types/, product categories are just a custom taxonomy with the internal name `product_cat`

Answer (score 0):

You can test if a post has a particular term assigned to it with the `has_term` function.

E.g.

```php
if ( has_term( 'term-slug', 'taxonomy-slug' ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

With this you can test if your "post" has a particular "term" ( aka if your "`product`" has a particular "`product_cat`" )

Comment: sorry not able to understand anything - hope my request is clear. for example if any product in the category men's leather shoes i want to display in the short description the SKU & the Material: Leather, and so on, that is it

Comment: I'm not sure which part you're having difficulty with, this is the solution to your problem. If I take your comment as an example: "for example if any `product` post has the term `mens leather shoes` in the `product_cat` taxonomy, aka `if ( has_term( 'mens shoes', 'product_cat' ) ) { echo "the SKU & the material leather and so on"; }`.

Comment: The fundamental missing information was that Product Categories is just a custom taxonomy, I recommend reading up on custom taxonomies and custom post types. Everything from shop orders to variations is either a custom post type or a custom taxonomy. Understanding this will make life much easier and allow you to work a lot faster

Comment: Can you share the full code that i need to just put it in the function file

Comment: My last comment is almost identical to what the end result would be, if you're looking for something you can blindly copy without even basic understanding then no I can't, even if I wanted to as you didn't share the slug of the product category you're trying to test for. But since I've already given you the code in the above comment, you could just replace `mens shoes` with the slug, you don't need my help to do a basic string replacement

Comment: not working - i'm not developer but a site owner, thank you. someone else will help